# Only works with Debug JS Remotely on Android

Tags: debugging, react-native, async-await, asyncstorage, aws-amplify

I'm using AsyncStorage to store a JWT token from AWS, but there is an unexpected behavior that I want to clarified.

This is my current code :

```
const retrieveJwt = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('jwt');
    if (value !== null) {
      return value;
    }
    else{      
      let user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
      let jwt = user.signInUserSession.accessToken.jwtToken;
      return jwt
    }
   } catch (error) {
     // Error retrieving data
     let user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
      let jwt = user.signInUserSession.accessToken.jwtToken;
      return jwt
   }
}

// AppSync init
const client = new Client({
  url: AppSync.graphqlEndpoint,
  region: AppSync.region,
  auth:{
    type: 'AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS',
    jwtToken: async () => await retrieveJwt(),
  },
  disableOffline: true
})
```

When I'm running this application I got this :

- Android real device without debugging : **Failed**
- Android real device with *Debug JS Remotely* : Success
- IOS simulator without debugging : Success
- IOS simulator with *Debug JS Remotely* : Success

The problem is that it seems that the JWT Token is not retrieve neither by AsyncStorage nor by AWS Auth Class, and I can't resolve it because :

1. I run on Android real device without debugging : doesn't work.
2. I run on Android with debugging : it works.

So I can't debug to see what is wrong because it works when I try to debug on Android.

Hope someone could help me.

Comment: A strange behavior that I still have not resolved...

Comment: I have a similar issue. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: I gave up the Apollo client, now I use API.graphql from aws-amplify package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue here.

My problem was not when I've read value from the `AsyncStorage`, but rather, when I've tried to save some value.

When I used the remote debugger everything did work fine, but without it an `Error` appeared.

The solution was to **convert the value to string before save them into the storage**.